# how to change glyph height without changing the font-size?

Tags: html, css, fonts, glyph

### Issue

for text elements that are adjacent to icon elements, the glyph height is not aligned with the icon height. the text elements are styled by CSS with `font-size: 20px;` and have consistent width for all their instances.

**here's an illustration:**

[image: font problem]

for the above case, the text should have the same height as the icon.

### Motivation

finding a way to make the letters a bit taller to take up the available vertical space, while keeping the `font-size` as is. how to do that?

### What have I tried?

to increase the `font-size` a bit, but came to conclusion i'll have to compromise for a smaller icon if I can't increase the letter height, thus the issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**You can** do it with css3 property `Scale`:  ([**demo on dabblet.com**](http://dabblet.com/gist/2922712))
[image]

**HTML markup:**

```
<span class="lower">lower size</span>
<span>normal size</span>
<span class="taller">taller size</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

span.lower{ transform: scaleY(0.9); }
span.taller { transform: scaleY(1.1); }
```

**Also,** you can try to set various values of `vertical-align` for images in your case:
`sub`, `super`, `bottom`, `top`, `middle`. This may help to solve your problem from another point.

Comment: Not working in my case but gonna accept this answer because obv. it solves the problem. The problem is somewhere in my code most probably.

Comment: I added note about using `vertical-align` for images, May be this can help you

Comment: Thanks, gonna play a bit with `vertical-align`. And thanks for the info I knew it that increasing of letter height was possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `line-height: 20px;` it will only increase the space between lines. It should help you match the element height.

And considering your calendar icon and text, add `vertical-align: middle;` to the image.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rBpKL/3/

Comment: Nope, this doesn't solve the problem, at least in my case. Maybe after all I'll increase the `font-size` but will wait a little longer to see if anyone knows a solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's almost as it should be. with `vertical-align` the images are positioned correctly but there's no space b/w the top and bottom image and adding `line-height` for the cell where all the data is doesn't fix this. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, by far this is the best looking variant I have.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot make letters taller without increasing font size—or changing font. In principle, you can decrease letter spacing, so that you could increase font size without increasing the width of the text. This is usually a bad idea, since it tends to make the font look worse and often less legible.

Showing the real problem in context (code or URL) might help to find a solution.

Comment: See tha main topic for image and explanation what I want to do.

Comment: @Leron do you want vertically center your label relatively to icons or truly make text taller?

Comment: Both would work but the problem is that the column is filled form a string containing  all the the text like `<img/>` tags, text and so on. So I decided that changing the letter size would be the easiest way